# Updating Xamarin app with servicestack

Tags: xamarin, servicestack

where is IosPclExportClient??

I used to use

```
PclExport.Configure(new IosPclExport());
```

But I have no idea what happened to `IosPclExport` - Now I see people are using

```
IosPclExportClient.Configure();
```

But `IosPclExportClient` isn't available?!

Why does all this have to change *all* *the* *time*?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [official API has never changed and only has ever been IosPclExportClient](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#initializing-pcl-client):

```
IosPclExportClient.Configure();
```

The class is defined in the `ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll` and should be added by NuGet when you add the **ServiceStack.Text** NuGet package. If it's not you can try removing and re-adding the NuGet package again, otherwise you can adding a manual reference to `ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll` from your NuGet packages folder.

Comment: Hard referenced it - was aactually in the client package... now getting .../iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT0034: Cannot include both 'monotouch.dll' and 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' in the same Xamarin.iOS project - 'Xamarin.iOS.dll' is referenced explicitly, while 'monotouch.dll' is referenced by 'ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. (MT0034) (SafeClaim.iOS)

Comment: You need to reference the `ServiceStack.Pcl.iOS.dll` from the `Xamarin.iOS10` NuGet folder (i.e. Unified API).

Comment: OK that did the trick - delete PCL packages - use Unified API - thank you :)

Comment: sorry @iwayneo. What do you mean " delete PCL packages - use Unified API"? I had the same problem. Please show me how to fix that more clearly. Thanks

Comment: I believe I was using the PCL packages - delete these and use the non PCL packages - these use the unified API and are the more recent builds - there is no need to use PCL specific packages here